# Error 403 when using Google Maps api with Flask

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I've been trying to use the Google Maps API in a Flask project I'm creating, but whenever I load the page, when I check the JavaScript console I get a 403 error like this:
[Google Maps Api error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQmPn.png)
I'm sure my API key is correct, and the map has everything with default values but the latitude, longitude, identifier and region. What could be causing this error, then?

This is the code itself:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_googlemaps import GoogleMaps
from flask_googlemaps import Map

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['GOOGLEMAPS_KEY'] = open("GOOGLE_API.txt").read()
GoogleMaps(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    mapa = Map(
        identifier="mapa",
        lat=36.53813063050466,
        lng=-6.202028173211203,
        region="es"
    )
    return flask.render_template("index.html", mapa=mapa)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

(Google API is where I store the API key)

Comment: Have you ensured there's no extra spaces, or newlines in the `GOOGLE_API.txt` file?

Comment: Yup, can confirm the GOOGLE_API.txt file only has the token itself.